# I am getting a type mismatch error on "Set ToolsMenu = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Tools")"

Tags: excel, vba, types, mismatch

On the following code I get a type mismatch and yet it looks as if the objects have the same type.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Aacro(1)
Dim ToolsMenu As CommandBarPopup
Dim NewMenuItem As CommandBarButton

MsgBox VarType(ToolsMenu)
MsgBox VarType(Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Tools"))

Set ToolsMenu = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Tools")
Set NewMenuItem = ToolsMenu.Controls("New Command")
Set NewMenuItem = ToolsMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

NewMenuItem.Caption = "New Command"
NewMenuItem.OnAction = "SayHello"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SayHello()
MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Was does TypeName(Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Tools")) give you?

Comment: ???`Sub Aacro(1)`???

Comment: OK there is a start. With TypeName(ToolsMenu) we get "Nothing" and  with TypeName(Application.CommandBars(..etc. we get "CommandBarControl".

Comment: Have a read through pages [1019-1027 VBA Programmer's Reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gkPLT_hBHjMC&pg=PA1024&lpg=PA1024&dq=index+CommandBarPopup&source=bl&ots=qzAnimgdJo&sig=o8uIc7j3mrRkK9ty_O-V2WKtEaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHif-ImZHcAhVBBcAKHVskBRQQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=index%20CommandBarPopup&f=false) to find the exact syntax you need.

Comment: Dim your vars as objects and give a try.

Comment: Since the introduction of the Ribbon menu in Office 2007, the only place you can show a toolbar is on the "Add-ins" ribbon tab.

shareedit
answered Oct 12 '17 at 6:24

Tim Williams
78.4k86077